# Shorten multiple elements with the same class in Sass

Tags: css, sass

In Sass you can write 
`.class1 .class2 {}` and `.class1 .class3 {}` as,

```
.class1 {
 &.class2, &.class3 {}
}
```

How do you shorten,

```
div.class1,
h2.class1,
p.class1 {}
```

This doesn't work as expected,

```
.class1 {
 & div, & h2, & p {}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the right idea, you just made a small error in your shortening.
Remove the space between `&` and the element, and nest the class `.class1` instead of the individual elements.

```
div, h2, p {
    &.class1 {}
}
```